# Passing string or wstring to macro in c++

Tags: c++, macros

How to pass string or wstring to macro and print string in macro
i am tried something below

```
#define JUMP_ON_FAILURE_MSG( ErrorCode , Text ) GET_ERROR( ErrorCode, #Text )

#define GET_ERROR( ErrorCode, Text)                                            \
{                                                                              \
    if (ErrorCode < 0)                                                         \
    {                                                                          \
        wprintf(L"Error :%s :[%d]", #Text , error_code);                              \
    }                                                                          \
}
```

Above macro does not print proper output i gets

```
Error :??????????? :[-5200]
```

text not gets printed

i am calling above code as

```
 JUMP_ON_FAILURE_MSG(-5200,L"Print error msg");
or
 JUMP_ON_FAILURE_MSG(-5200,"Print error msg");
```

Please help

Comment: Make it `Text`, not `#Text` for both.

Comment: What `#` is doing in `#Text`?

Comment: Sorry but ,I am tried to do it stringizing i was hopping it will work

Comment: Thanks it worked after removing # @Rapptz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others already pointed out in the comments you have to write

```
#define JUMP_ON_FAILURE_MSG( ErrorCode , Text ) GET_ERROR( ErrorCode, Text )
```

for instance. Without the `#`.

For further reference look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace).